# Is there a way to open ctrl-clicked target-blank links right next to the tab from which I open them?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

First of all, neither `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent=true` nor Tab Mix Plus option helps. I just have a page containing `a href="..." target="_blank"` (or without `target="_blank"`) links. I ctrl-click them, but each opened tab just appends **far to the right** so it may be not even visible! How do I force each tab (opened by ctrl-clicking a link) to open **just next** to the active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Tab Utilities instead. Generally Tab Mix Plus would work.

Comment: Linking to the suggestions and describing what they do would be helpful.

Comment: I've got it: Tab Utilities Options --> Tabs --> Tab Opening --> Open new tabs next to current tab which are from: select "All" + **uncheck** "Keep the original order for continuous background tabs"

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:config` in Firefox location bar.  Search for value `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` and set the value to true and it should work.